# Null pointer Exception when viewing image using ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android

I  am having a folder structure and files on SDCard.When i'm trying to view images using ACTION_VIEW,images in  folders are viewed by imgeviewer.The problem is when i'm to opening an image from a **folder with special characters** i'm unable to view  the images.

The exception is ***got exception decoding bitmap java.lang.NullPointerException***.

When i'm checking the folder exists or not,the answer is yes.ImageViewer is not able to view the files in folders with specialcharacters.

**Note**: When I tried to create folder with encoded special characters and tried to view image,the problem persists.

Thanks  & Regards,
Sha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the Url to parse before passing to Intent.

```
      `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       Uri data = Uri.parse(UrlEncoder.encode(ParentFolderPath)+"/test.jpg");
       intent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");
       startActivity(intent);`
```

Regards,
sha